# why javaFX 8 Media framework needs libavcodec53 and libavformat53 in linux?

Tags: java, javafx, mp3

i searched and found javafx 8 media framework is implemented on gstreamer framework in linux. and [JavaFX Supported System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) says libavcodec53 and libavformat53 are required in order to support AAC audio, MP3 audio, H.264 video, and HTTP Live Streaming.

my question is :
if javafx 8  media framework is based on gstreamer framework , why gstreamer-0_10-plugins-fluendo_mp3 or gstreamer-0_10-plugins-ffmpeg or any other useful plugins are not used to play mp3 file but requiring aditional libav* packages installed ?